# How to pass functions in Steps in antD?

Tags: reactjs, antd

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/switch-step-ant-design-demo-forked-cwcp8?file=/index.js

I have two doubts:

1. How do I pass functions (`content1(), content2()`) inside the content?
2. How do I restrict the Next Button, (to be performed only when a certain condition gets fulfilled in
   the present page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To your first doubt**

You are returning jsx so you can render it by just doing `<content1 />`. I suggest make it a component outside your class component. Make it also the first letter capital:

```
const Content1 = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Content 1</div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me to go to content 2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: 0,
    step: [
      {
        title: "First",
        content: <Content1 onClick={() => this.click()} />
      },
      {
        title: "Second",
        content: <Content2 />
      },
      {
        title: "Last",
        content: <Content3 />
      }
    ],
    isPageOneOk: false
    
    ...

};
```

**To your second doubt**

Just track the `current` state on your `next` function and just increment the `current` state if a condition fulfilled:

```
click = () => {
  alert("you can go now to content 2");
  this.setState({
    isPageOneOk: true
  });
};

next = () => {
  const {current, isPageOneOk} = this.state;

  if (current === 0 && !isPageOneOk) {
    alert("Can't go to next page")
  } else {
    //increment current state to go to next content
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }
};
```

Take note that on each step, current content will unmount to the dom.

Here's the complete sample code:

[image: Edit]